# @RestControllerAdvice not able to catch basic AuthenticationException through custom authentication entrypoint

Tags: spring, exception, spring-security, error-handling

My requirement to catch basic auth exception in controller advice

For that used the below code for authentication entrypoint,
@Component("delegatedAuthenticationEntryPoint")
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

```
@Override
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.writeValue(out, response);
    out.flush();

}
```

}

in filterchain passing the same as below ,
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

```
    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> {
                authorize.anyRequest().authenticated();
            })
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .exceptionHandling(httpSecurityExceptionHandlingConfigurer -> httpSecurityExceptionHandlingConfigurer.authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint));

    return http.build();

}
```

In RestControllerAdvice catching like below ,

@ExceptionHandler({ AuthenticationException.class, BadCredentialsException.class })
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
public ErrorDetails handleAuthenticationException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(simpleDateFormat.format(new Date()), ex.getMessage(), request.getDescription(false));
return errorDetails;
}

But it still not working , need help to resolve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Because the exception that occurred in Entrypoint is handled inside the Filter Chain, the exception will not be able to be handed out by @RestControllerAdvice because the exception is not propagated to the DispatcherServlet.

If you want to handle authentication exceptions in @RestControllerAdvice, you will need to consider propagating the exception raised by the filter to the Dispatcher servlet!